# Where do you get NEAR Protocol testnet tokens (faucet)?

Tags: nearprotocol

Where can someone increase the number of tokens on their TestNet account on NEAR Protocol if they run out?

Comment: Create another testnet account and transfer funds to your original account?

Comment: You can get Near testenet tokens here: https://near-faucet.io/ It's a non-official faucet where people contribute testnet tokens; you can get tokens from there.

Answer (score 9):

Correct answer from the comment:

> Create another testnet account and transfer funds to your original account

Comment: While that's the correct answer, its by far the worse answer possible as it just leads to people polluting the testnet namespace to get NEAR just to do development.

Answer (score 3):

While it's somewhat similar approach I think the better way would be to create developer account through `near-cli` and then delete it by specifying your original account id as the `<beneficiaryId>`

example *(using near-cli)*:

> > near dev-deploy
>
> Starting deployment. Account id: dev-1649926001453-26756682200890, node: https://rpc.testnet.near.org, helper: https://helper.testnet.near.org, file: ./out/main.wasm

This should give you the new dev account with account id of `dev-1649926001453-26756682200890` in my case *(just ignore the latter errors)*. it will have 200 NEAR tokens on it's balance. now you can delete this account by specifying your original account id as beneficiary:

> > near delete dev-1649926001453-26756682200890 satoshi.testnet

> Deleting account. Account id: dev-1649926001453-26756682200890, node: https://rpc.testnet.near.org, helper: https://helper.testnet.near.org, beneficiary: satoshi.testnet

Now you should have +200 NEAR tokens on satoshi.testnet and the previous account should be deleted so no testnet cluster will be poluted through the process.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it on https://near-faucet.io/

This faucet is a community project where you can currently request up to 100Ⓝ testnet Near every ~30min. It is run on donations so if you have any unused tokens please consider sharing them with our fellow testnetters.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command

> near dev-deploy --wasmFile target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/test_token.wasm

This will create a new account with 200 NEAR balance.
And then run this commnad

> near delete dev-1657004862852-68973388844970 `Your accountId`.testnet

You will get 200 NEAR in your account :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another faucet from the examples page:

https://near-examples.github.io/token-printer/

It looks like it's loaded with a bunch of tokens, and it makes you produce a PoW hash in order to transfer 100 NEAR to your account. Usually this takes about a minute. Don't abuse it!